# ionic 2 page redirections

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am using ionic 2.

Here is my submit function.

```
submit(){

    if(this.ImageURL != undefined)
    {
       var fileName = 'sample-' + new Date().getTime() + '.jpg';
       let uploadTask = this.firebase.storage().ref('profile/' + fileName);
        console.log(this.updateprofile.value);
         var upload = uploadTask.put(this.getURL).then((snapshot) => {
         this.updateprofile.controls['FILE'].setValue(snapshot.a.downloadURLs[0]); 
         var val=this.af.database.list('/users');
         val.update(this.key,this.updateprofile.value);
         this.platform.ready().then(() => {
            window.plugins.toast.show("Profile updated success", "short",'bottom',1000);
       });

     });
    }
   if(this.ImageURL === undefined)
   {
      console.log(this.updateprofile.value);
     var val=this.af.database.list('/users');
     val.update(this.key,this.updateprofile.value);
     this.platform.ready().then(() => {
              window.plugins.toast.show("Profile update success", "short",'bottom',1000);

         });

   }
  }
```

here is my template code

```
<ion-content padding>
     <ion-card  *ngIf="editvalue===false" class="card2">
       <div>
           <img  *ngIf="File" class="image2" [src]="File" imageViewer/>
           <img  *ngIf="!File" class="image2" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonage/images/f/f4/User-info.png/revision/latest?cb=20100528043005" imageViewer/>
       </div>
      <p (click)="Edit()"> <ion-icon ios="ios-create" md="md-create"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit Profile</p>

        <ion-list class="listview">
             <ion-item *ngIf="Firstname">
                 <ion-icon name="ios-person-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                 <h5>{{Firstname}}</h5>
             </ion-item>

             <ion-item *ngIf="Lastname">
                 <ion-icon name="ios-person-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                 <h5>{{Lastname}}</h5>
             </ion-item>

             <ion-item *ngIf="Gender">
                 <ion-icon name="ios-person-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                 <h5>{{Gender}}</h5>
             </ion-item>

             <ion-item *ngIf="Address">
                 <ion-icon name="ios-home-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                 <h5>{{Address}}</h5>
             </ion-item>

             <ion-item *ngIf="Email">
                 <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                 <h5>{{Email}}</h5>
             </ion-item>

             <ion-item *ngIf="Mobile">
                 <ion-icon name="ios-call-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                 <h5>{{Mobile}}</h5>
             </ion-item>
        </ion-list> 
     </ion-card>

      <ion-card *ngIf="editvalue===true" class="parent">
         <form [formGroup]="updateprofile" (ngSubmit)="submit($event)" novalidate >
                <div>
                    <img (click)="upload()" *ngIf="ImageURL" class="image2" [src]="ImageURL">
                    <img  *ngIf="File" class="image2" [src]="File" imageViewer/>
                    <img (click)="upload()" *ngIf="!File && !ImageURL " class="image2" src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/dragonage/images/f/f4/User-info.png/revision/latest?cb=20100528043005" imageViewer/>
                </div>
                    <h6 (click)="upload()">Edit Photo</h6>
                    <p (click)="view()"><ion-icon name="eye"></ion-icon>&nbsp;&nbsp;View Profile</p>
                <ion-list>
                    <ion-item >
                       <ion-label floating >First Name</ion-label>
                        <ion-icon name="ios-person-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="text" name="FirstName"  formControlName="FIRST_NAME"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item >
                        <ion-label floating >Last Name</ion-label>
                        <ion-icon name="ios-person-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="text" name="FirstName" formControlName="LAST_NAME"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item >
                        <ion-label floating >Address</ion-label>
                         <ion-icon name="ios-home-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="text" name="FirstName" formControlName="ADDRESS"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>Email</ion-label>
                        <ion-icon name="ios-mail-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="email" disabled="true" name="Email" formControlName="EMAIL"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                       <ion-label floating>Mobile 1</ion-label>
                       <ion-icon name="ios-call-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                       <ion-input type="text" name="Username" formControlName="MOBILE1"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label floating>Mobile 2</ion-label>
                        <ion-icon name="ios-call-outline" item-left></ion-icon>
                        <ion-input type="text" name="Username" formControlName="MOBILE2"></ion-input>
                    </ion-item>

                    <ion-item>
                        <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
                        <ion-select formControlName="GENDER">
                            <ion-option value="Female">Female</ion-option>
                            <ion-option value="Male">Male</ion-option>
                        </ion-select>
                    </ion-item>
                </ion-list>

                     <div class="btn">
                        <button ion-button >Update</button>
                     </div>
            </form>
     </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

Its work perfectly.But it automatically redirects to rootpage.

Actually i did not write any functionality in page for redirection.

How can i fix this issue.

Kindly advice me.

Thanks.

Comment: where you are calling this submit function?on a `button` or somewhere else like on a `div`?

Comment: Thanks.I called this function in form submission

Comment: have you tried event.preventDefault()?

Comment: event.preventDefault() is not working..I had the same problem last week ..@ANISUNDAR I dont know the reason but it is resolved when I called that function on a button instead of a div

Comment: I tried this way <div class="btn" (click)="submit($event)"><button ion-button >Update</button> </div> But still i have same issue.

Comment: @varunaaruru.I also used div inside a button.It's work only browser.Not work in mobile..

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are calling this function on form submission and you may have set default page to rootpage.

Call submit method from update button click.

Your template should look like below:

```
<form [formGroup]="updateprofile" novalidate >

  <!-- Your form content -->

 <div class="btn">

    <button ion-button (click)="submit()">Update</button>

  </div>  

</form>
```

Comment: try clearing the cache. your browser might have cached older files.